# Getting PHP to work with SPDY?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mod-fcgid, spdy

I recently switched my site over to using HTTPS in all the URL's. [(My post here)](https://serverfault.com/questions/570288/is-it-bad-to-redirect-http-to-https)

I am running Apache with PHP on Ubuntu 12.0.4

I was told that I should install the Apache module for SPDY since I am using SSL / HTTPS so I followed the directions on this site to install it, it installed without a problem... https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/mod_spdy/

My problems start with PHP... if you view this page https://developers.google.com/speed/spdy/mod_spdy/php you can read about using PHP with SPDY

Basically it says that you need to use `mod_fcgid` instead of `mod_php`

My server currently uses `mod_php` for all my sites to run.  So I installed the `mod_fcgid` handler and it installed without an issue.  The problem was when I try to re-boot Apache.  Things went crazy due to the content in my Apach config files.

from my `http.conf` file...

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
    php_flag track_vars On
    php_flag register_globals Off
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/zpanel/temp
</IfModule>
```

Changing the `mod_php5` above to use the new `mod_fcgid` does not resolve my issues, it instead says that there is a problem with things like `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off` it appears `php_flag` is not valid when using `mod_fcgid` ?

Sorry I don't have the exact errors now as I have restored my server back to mod_php so that it will work.

Everywhere in my config files where I have calls to `mod_fcgid` seemed to through an error though.

Any ideas how I can get this working?

Comment: Use a test server with a copy of your existing configuration to experiment.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using mod_fcgid apache doesn't know anything about php anymore. It simply sends it off. So those configurations can't be in any apache configs. You'll need to add those settings to php.ini.

http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-centos-6.2