# Why don't the nginx and apache sites redirect http to https automatically?

Tags: ssl, https

These days, many sites automatically redirect `http` requests to `https`.

This would seem like a [good thing](https://serverfault.com/a/570290).

However, there are still some, most notably http://nginx.org/ and http://www.apache.org/, that do *not* redirect to `https`.

These people write server software, so I guess they must know what they are doing. This makes me wonder:

Is there a compelling reason for these sites not to redirect to `https` automatically?

Comment: both `http://nginx.org` and `http://www.apache.org` return `307 Internal Redirect` for me and then reroute me to https. I'm using Brave browser.

Comment: @Moses: Strange. I'm not seeing any redirects in the Firefox network console. Just the `200 OK`.

Comment: There could be a variety of reasons. Who's to say? Could try contacting them and see what answers they provide.